# Find distance in meters using latitude and longitude of two different point in android

Tags: android, distance, latitude-longitude

I'm working on finding a distance between 2 points using `lat` and `long`.

I have followed these codes.

```
    /* double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return (dist);*/

    Log.e("distancefinder","Past   lat: "+lat1);
    Log.e("distancefinder","Past   long: "+lon1);
    Log.e("distancefinder","current lat : "+lat2);
    Log.e("distancefinder","current long : "+lon2);

    int R = 6371; // km
    double dLat = toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLon = toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = toRadians(lat2);

    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return R * c;

    /*      double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters

    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * 
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;*/


    /*      double distance;
    Location locationA = new Location("");
    locationA.setLatitude(lat1);
    locationA.setLongitude(lon1);
    Location locationB = new Location("");
    locationB.setLatitude(lat2);
    locationB.setLongitude(lon2);
    distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);   //in meters
    return distance;*/
    //      distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;   //in km
```

But I didn't get accurate distance in meters. Here is my log cat results :

```
11-20 12:28:15.621: E/distancefinder(5309): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:15.621: E/distancefinder(5309): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:28:25.384: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:25.384: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:28:30.380: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:30.381: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:28:35.404: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:35.404: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876692
11-20 12:28:35.404: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950608
11-20 12:28:35.404: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876766
11-20 12:28:35.404: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950719
11-20 12:28:35.404: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0014572341093100844
11-20 12:28:35.417: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 1.4572341093100845
11-20 12:28:40.399: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:40.399: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:28:45.403: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:45.403: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:28:50.412: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:50.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:28:55.398: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:28:55.398: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:00.381: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:00.381: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876766
11-20 12:29:00.381: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950719
11-20 12:29:00.381: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876807
11-20 12:29:00.381: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950323
11-20 12:29:00.382: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.004314827685750207
11-20 12:29:00.387: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 4.314827685750207
11-20 12:29:05.407: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:05.407: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:10.408: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:10.408: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:15.401: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:15.401: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:20.405: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:20.405: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:25.386: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:25.386: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876807
11-20 12:29:25.386: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950323
11-20 12:29:25.386: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876729
11-20 12:29:25.386: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950339
11-20 12:29:25.387: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :8.844764712143432E-4
11-20 12:29:25.396: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 0.8844764712143431
11-20 12:29:30.392: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:30.392: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:35.393: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:35.393: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:40.401: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:40.402: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:45.386: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:45.386: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:29:50.403: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:50.403: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876729
11-20 12:29:50.403: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950339
11-20 12:29:50.403: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876932
11-20 12:29:50.403: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950936
11-20 12:29:50.403: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0068510533659564225
11-20 12:29:50.418: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 6.851053365956423
11-20 12:29:55.404: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:29:55.404: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:00.401: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:00.401: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:05.381: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:05.381: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:10.419: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:10.419: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:15.386: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:15.387: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876932
11-20 12:30:15.387: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950936
11-20 12:30:15.387: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876918
11-20 12:30:15.387: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950864
11-20 12:30:15.387: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :7.955033100235504E-4
11-20 12:30:15.394: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 0.7955033100235503
11-20 12:30:20.373: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:20.373: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:25.401: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:25.401: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:30.411: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:30.411: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:35.391: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:35.391: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:40.383: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:40.384: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876918
11-20 12:30:40.384: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950864
11-20 12:30:40.384: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876826
11-20 12:30:40.384: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950311
11-20 12:30:40.384: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.006078478068578999
11-20 12:30:40.392: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 6.078478068578999
11-20 12:30:45.532: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:45.532: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:50.402: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:50.402: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:30:55.412: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:30:55.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:00.409: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:00.409: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:05.387: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:05.387: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876826
11-20 12:31:05.387: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950311
11-20 12:31:05.387: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.987683
11-20 12:31:05.387: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950143
11-20 12:31:05.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0018208297478854096
11-20 12:31:05.395: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 1.8208297478854096
11-20 12:31:10.399: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:10.399: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:15.405: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:15.405: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:20.405: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:20.405: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:25.411: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:25.418: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.987683
11-20 12:31:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950143
11-20 12:31:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876792
11-20 12:31:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950169
11-20 12:31:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :5.078402770198048E-4
11-20 12:31:30.423: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 0.5078402770198048
11-20 12:31:35.410: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:35.410: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:40.405: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:40.405: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:45.395: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:45.395: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:50.407: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:50.407: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:31:55.399: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:31:55.399: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876792
11-20 12:31:55.399: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950169
11-20 12:31:55.399: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876777
11-20 12:31:55.399: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950228
11-20 12:31:55.399: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :6.606681020544278E-4
11-20 12:31:55.414: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 0.6606681020544278
11-20 12:32:00.404: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:00.404: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:05.404: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:05.404: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:10.418: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:10.418: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:15.414: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:15.414: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:20.392: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:20.392: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876777
11-20 12:32:20.392: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950228
11-20 12:32:20.392: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876642
11-20 12:32:20.392: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950319
11-20 12:32:20.393: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0017959869680722845
11-20 12:32:20.403: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 1.7959869680722844
11-20 12:32:25.410: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:25.410: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:30.409: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:30.410: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:35.399: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:35.399: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:40.403: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:40.403: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:45.412: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:45.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876642
11-20 12:32:45.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950319
11-20 12:32:45.412: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876828
11-20 12:32:45.412: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950043
11-20 12:32:45.413: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0036359967167283705
11-20 12:32:45.425: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 3.6359967167283704
11-20 12:32:50.435: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:50.435: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:32:55.420: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:32:55.420: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:00.405: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:00.405: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:05.407: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:05.407: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:10.410: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:10.411: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876828
11-20 12:33:10.411: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950043
11-20 12:33:10.411: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876684
11-20 12:33:10.411: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950334
11-20 12:33:10.411: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0035362761324678593
11-20 12:33:10.419: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 3.5362761324678593
11-20 12:33:15.411: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:15.411: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:20.392: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:20.393: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:25.408: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:25.408: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:30.427: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:30.427: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:35.387: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:35.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876684
11-20 12:33:35.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950334
11-20 12:33:35.388: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876785
11-20 12:33:35.388: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950269
11-20 12:33:35.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :0.0013256282494112776
11-20 12:33:35.397: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 1.3256282494112777
11-20 12:33:40.408: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:40.408: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:45.410: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:45.410: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:50.413: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:50.413: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:33:55.416: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:33:55.416: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:34:00.412: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:00.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876785
11-20 12:34:00.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.5950269
11-20 12:34:00.414: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876793
11-20 12:34:00.414: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.595028
11-20 12:34:00.414: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :1.4872230719746918E-4
11-20 12:34:00.425: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 0.14872230719746918
11-20 12:34:05.417: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:05.417: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:34:10.408: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:10.410: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:34:15.411: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:15.411: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:34:20.408: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:20.408: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:34:25.388: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:25.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   lat: 12.9876793
11-20 12:34:25.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Past   long: 77.595028
11-20 12:34:25.388: E/distancefinder(5592): current lat : 12.9876759
11-20 12:34:25.388: E/distancefinder(5592): current long : 77.5950243
11-20 12:34:25.388: E/distancefinder(5592): Distance in km :5.510439055217952E-4
11-20 12:34:25.395: E/distancefinder(5592):  Distance in mts : 0.5510439055217952
11-20 12:34:30.415: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:30.415: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
11-20 12:34:35.412: E/distancefinder(5592): compare lat and long
11-20 12:34:35.412: E/distancefinder(5592): Same latitude and longtitude and return false
```

So, what is the solution for this. Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using google map V2 API you can use below code which gives you accurate result
 //Say you have

```
 LatLng latLong1,latLong2;
 latLong1=new LatLng(12.77, 77.88);
 latLong2=new LatLng(17.77, 74.88);

 //Convert latLong to location object

 Location location1=new Location("location1");
 location1.setLongitude(latLong1.latitude);
 location1.setLongitude(latLong1.longitude);

 Location location2=new Location("location2");
 location2.setLongitude(latLong2.latitude);
 location2.setLongitude(latLong2.longitude);

 float  distanceInMeters= location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to calculate distance b/w two lant lngs.

```
public static float calculateDistanceBetweenTwoPoints(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double toLat, Double toLng){
        float[] results = new float[2];
        Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, toLat, toLng, results);
        float distanceInMeters = results[0];
        return distanceInMeters;
    }
```

Comment: @Gowtham what problem you are facing?

Comment: Actually i want to get distance from one point to another using lat and long(past and current location).I'm in the same location and there is small variation in the lat and long. For that variation i'm getting 3,10,1,4 etc distance in meters.I'm not getting exact distance.

Comment: Past   lat: 12.9876745
 Past   long: 77.5950088
 current lat : 12.9876746
 current long : 77.5950851

 Distance in mts : 8.277802467346191
 
 

 Past   lat: 12.9876746
 Past   long: 77.5950851
 current lat : 12.9876822
 current long : 77.5950331

  Distance in mts : 5.703795909881592

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.remo.distancefinder;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GPSservice extends Service{

    private Context main_context;
    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    private Handler handler= new Handler();
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private Distance pastDistance = new Distance();
    private Distance currentDistance = new Distance();
    public static double DISTANCE;
    boolean flag = true ;
    private double totalDistance ;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("distancefinder","service started");

        main_context = getApplicationContext();
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(main_context);

        pastDistance.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude());
        pastDistance.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude());

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        currentDistance.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude());
                        currentDistance.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude());
                        Toast.makeText(main_context, "latitude:"+gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude()+
                                "Longitude:"+gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        comapre_LatitudeLongitude();
                        /*                      if(flag){
                            pastDistance.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude());
                            pastDistance.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude());
                            flag = false;
                        }else{
                            Log.e("distancefinder","In else statement");
                            currentDistance.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLatitude());
                            currentDistance.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLocation().getLongitude());
                            flag = comapre_LatitudeLongitude();
                        }*/



                    }
                });


            }
        };

        timer.schedule(timerTask,0, 5000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    /*  private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
                double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);

        Log.e("distancefinder","Past   lat: "+lat1);
        Log.e("distancefinder","Past   long: "+lon1);
        Log.e("distancefinder","current lat : "+lat2);
        Log.e("distancefinder","current long : "+lon2);

        int R = 6371; // km
        double dLat = toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLon = toRadians(lon2-lon1);
        lat1 = toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = toRadians(lat2);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
        return R * c;

                double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters

        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * 
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

        return dist;


                double distance;
        Location locationA = new Location("");
        locationA.setLatitude(lat1);
        locationA.setLongitude(lon1);
        Location locationB = new Location("");
        locationB.setLatitude(lat2);
        locationB.setLongitude(lon2);
        distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);   //in meters
        return distance;
        //      distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000;   //in km
    }


    public double toRadians(double deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI/180);
    }

    private double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    private double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
    }*/

    public float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {

        Log.e("distancefinder","Past   lat: "+lat1);
        Log.e("distancefinder","Past   long: "+lng1);
        Log.e("distancefinder","current lat : "+lat2);
        Log.e("distancefinder","current long : "+lng2);

        double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

        return dist;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------onDestroy -stop service ");
        timer.cancel();
        DISTANCE = totalDistance ;
    }

    public void comapre_LatitudeLongitude(){
        Log.e("distancefinder","compare lat and long");

        if(pastDistance.getLatitude() == currentDistance.getLatitude() && pastDistance.getLongitude() == currentDistance.getLongitude()){
            Log.e("distancefinder","Same latitude and longtitude and return false");
            //          return false;
        }else{
            final double distance = distFrom((float)pastDistance.getLatitude(),(float)pastDistance.getLongitude(),(float)currentDistance.getLatitude(),(float)currentDistance.getLongitude());
            Log.e("distancefinder","Distance in km :"+distance);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    /*float kilometer=1.609344f;
                    Log.e("distancefinder","Total distance initial"+distance);
                    totalDistance = totalDistance +  distance * kilometer*/;
                    //DISTANCE = distance;
                    pastDistance.setLatitude(currentDistance.getLatitude());
                    pastDistance.setLongitude(currentDistance.getLongitude());
                    Log.e("distancefinder"," Distance in mts : "+distance);
                    Toast.makeText(main_context, "distance in mtrs:"+distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            //          return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation for getting `double a` looks wrong, and I'm not sure what you're doing with `toRadians()` (is that a method or should it be `Math.toRadians()`?). I use the method below and it works without issues (returns distance in kilometers to one decimal point but you can change that to whatever you need).

```
public static double getDistance(double deviceLatitude, double deviceLongitude,
    double destinationLatitude, double destinationLongitude) {
    double distanceLatitude = Math.toRadians(deviceLatitude - destinationLatitude);
    double distanceLongitude = Math.toRadians(deviceLongitude - destinationLongitude);
    double a = Math.sin(distanceLatitude / 2)
        * Math.sin(distanceLatitude / 2)
        + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(destinationLatitude))
        * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(deviceLatitude))
        * Math.sin(distanceLongitude / 2)
        * Math.sin(distanceLongitude / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return Double.valueOf(new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(6371 * c));
}
```